# Replace characters with accents - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've been searching for a solution to my issue and cant find anything at all.

I want to replace the content of a NSString like this "DepÃ³sitos y PrÃ©stamos" into this "Depósitos y Préstamos".

Any Idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the strings coming from? It appears you are using the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the NSString method

```
-(NSString*)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:
```

for each accentuated symbol. For example, for the ó in Depósitos, you could use this:

```
NSString *depositosCorrecto = [depositosIncorrecto stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ã³" withString:@"ó"];
```

So, how can you get those extrange symbols in xCode? Just do as i did, copy an paste them from where you're getting it written.

Hope it helps!

Lucas

**EDIT**

I found [this table](http://david.xn--cantn-3ta.com/blog/informatica/tabla-de-equivalencias-de-caracteres-no-ascii/583/) that may be helpful.

Comment: Have you tested it?  I don't know if 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString' will do the job when it comes to replacing accent letters.

Comment: This doesn't account for composed and decomposed characters nor the fact there is a many to many relationship between characters and glyphs.

Comment: @TBlue Yes, i have tested it and it works. Here is a [table with special characters](http://david.xn--cantn-3ta.com/blog/informatica/tabla-de-equivalencias-de-caracteres-no-ascii/583/)